# Token that returned from the method getIdToken() is too long, does this correct or there is something error?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Sign in OAuth 2.0, but I have inquiry why the token returned from the method getIdToken() is very too long such as the following:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ1ZWViYzRjOWY5NGVkMzVhYWE5YTdiZTUyYzM0YTNmZDUwZGQ4ODkifQ.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.FCsDYU7S8TEKrbm6VxBVXaJlLzrzPuXTP_z14RMIzMZohWNOpHwLYFQivkzy1mC6KJ67qECv0MI5Ap14R2vkxr7XtU9dyZH6oWBvDOgW6KYyBazEi5214Rp-uUeFXDEDFIY_mSOaS0mjlU8N9UxZfr4zIRY6R1p2JI4l1RWOb_rid8bT4gNpA6LFeop9BtmaOeSSuOfmLheqw5Uz3Ws2WCGdu857-rTZc3W5ywfbckvkZN72CRgrKUAeRbcHuGndX83NRpBFdHChXr4FIVT3tWWjiMRsCxLTvDNxXClV269IP9tXELhqNBACdPEX60hRX-DgXPSGl9SQ85IY090nuQ
```

Comment: hi! have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google Signin produces a compact serialized JSON Web Token (JWT, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) to represent the authenticated user. That token is self-contained and contains information about the user in a verifiable way. You can verify that your token is a valid JWT at: http://jwt.io So yes, it is a valid token and it gets very large as more information is embedded in it.

Comment: I checked on my token at: http://jwt.io  and got a true data on the Section of Data Payload but also I got Invalid Signature, What is this means ?